# Huge difference in execution plans and running times due to just one degree of parallelism

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, parallel-processing, oracle19c

Could anyone shed some light on what the optimizer is doing and why the latter execution time is so much slower given the exact same query and the difference of just 1 degree of parallelism.

The query in question:

```
SELECT
/*+ PARALLEL(X) */
ID,
MAX(COL_AB) OVER (PARTITION BY COL_CD) AS COL_AB,
COL_CD
FROM (
     SELECT
     ID,
     COALESCE(COL_A, COL_B) AS COL_AB,
     COALESCE(COL_C, COL_D) AS COL_CD
     FROM MY_TABLE
     WHERE FLAG = 1.0
);
```

By trial-and-error, we found that if the degree of parallelism is <=6, the query runs in ~1.5 min, whereas if the degree is >= 7, the running time is ~1.3 hrs. The threshold-like effect is due to very different [execution plans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggk56.png), with the former involving 700K I/O requests and the latter 26M. Why is it choosing such an inefficient execution plan and is there a way to work around it without having to experiment with the degree?

Version of the database is Oracle 19c EE Extreme Perf Release 19.18.0.0.0

Comment: The difference between 700K IO and 26M IO is because the latter plan uses full table scan while the former one uses index access (which is not very selective). Regardless of `batched` in index access the rows/blocks ratio seems to be too low (32M rows of index produce 26M read requests), so it effectively performs row-by-row reads from the table (and not batched). What is a parallel degree of the index used? What does the optimizer trace for 10053 event tell about this decision?

Comment: @astentx sorry for newbie questions, how do I look these things up?

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather write the query like below:

```
SELECT
/*+ PARALLEL(6) */
ID,
MAX(COL_AB) OVER (PARTITION BY COL_CD) AS COL_AB,
COL_CD
FROM (
     SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(6) */
     ID,
     COALESCE(COL_A, COL_B) AS COL_AB,
     COALESCE(COL_C, COL_D) AS COL_CD
     FROM MY_TABLE
     WHERE FLAG = 1.0
);
```

Not sure whether the increase of the indicated parallel threads is what caused the query to run slower when using /*+ PARALLEL(6) */. It may have run slower that time because something else requiring lots of resources was going on in the database at that time. How many parallel threads you have depends on how many processors may be allocated for that query. You should have checked in sys.gv_$session and sys.gv_$session_longops to see what was going on at that time.